# Copy text file from docker container to host

Tags: docker

I have a docker container with an application running inside of it. I am trying to export a text file from the docker container to the host. The problem is the application keeps on writing data into the text file at regular intervals.

Is there a way to directly store the file onto the host and the application inside the docker container keep storing the data to the text file?

Comment: Use bind mounts or volume.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) or [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). They are used to achieve exactly what you asked.